# Why am I getting "Cannot access 'server' before initialization" error in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, environment, hoisting

I am getting the dreaded `Cannot access 'server' before initialization` error in code that is identical to code that's running in production.

The only things that have changed are my OS version (macOS 10.11->10.14) my NodeJS version (10->12) and my VSCode `launch.json`, but I cannot see anything in either that would cause an issue.  My Node version went from 10 to 12, but in production it went from 8 to 15 without issue. I routinely keep `launch.json` pretty sparse, and the same error happens using `node server` in Terminal.

Here is the offending code.  The issue occurs because I have `shutdown()` defined before `server` and it references `server`.  It's written to add an event-handler and then cause the event.  Yes, it could be refactored but it already works. It works, really.  In 21 instances spread over 7 servers.

I have tried changing the declaraion/init of `server` from `const` to `var` but that does not fix it.  As mentioned,  *this is code that's running in prod*!  What's wrong with my environment?

Maybe a better question is: why did this ever work?

```
'use strict'

const fs = require('fs');
const https = require('https');
const cyp = require('crypto').constants;
const stoppable = require('./common/stoppable.js');
const hu = require('./common/hostutil');

process.on('uncaughtException', err => {
  wslog.error(`Uncaught Exception: ${err} ${err.stack}`);
  shutdown();
});

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, p) => {
  wslog.error(`Unhandled Promise Rejection: ${reason} - ${p}`);
});

// 'shutdown' is a known static string sent from node-windows wrapper.js if the service is stopped
process.on('message', m => {
  if (m == 'shutdown') {
    wslog.info(`${wsconfig.appName} has received shutdown message`);
    shutdown();
  }
});

process.on('SIGTERM', shutdown);
process.on('SIGINT', shutdown);
process.on('SIGHUP', shutdown);

function shutdown() {
  httpStatus = 503; // Unavailable
  wslog.info(`${wsconfig.appName} httpStatus now ${httpStatus} - stopping server...`);
// Error happens on this next line; It should not execute till after server is running already
  server.on('close', function () {
    wslog.info(`${wsconfig.appName} HTTP server has stopped, now exiting process.`);
    process.exit(0)
  });
  server.stop();
}

// Init and start the web server/listener
var combiCertFile = fs.readFileSync(wsconfig.keyFile, 'utf8');
var certAuthorityFile = fs.readFileSync(wsconfig.caFile, 'utf8');

var serverOptions = {
  key: combiCertFile,
  cert: combiCertFile,
  ca: certAuthorityFile,
  passphrase: wsconfig.certPass,
  secureOptions: cyp.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1 | cyp.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_1
};

var server = https.createServer(serverOptions, global.app)
  .listen(wsconfig.port, function () {
    wslog.info(`listening on port ${wsconfig.port}.`);
  });

server.on('clientError', (err, socket) => {
  if (err.code === 'ECONNRESET' || !socket.writable) { return; }
  // ECONNRESET was already logged in socket.on.error. Here, we log others.
  wslog.warn(`Client error: ${err} ${err.stack}`);
  socket.end('HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\n\r\n');
});

server.on('error', (err)=>{
  if ( err.code === 'EADDRINUSE' ) {
    wslog.error(`${err.code} FATAL - Another ${wsconfig.appName} or app is using my port! ${wsconfig.port}`);
  } else {
    wslog.error(`${err.code} FATAL - Server error: ${err.stack}`);
  }
  shutdown();
})

combiCertFile = null;
certAuthorityFile = null;

// Post-instantiation configuration required (may differ between apps: need an indirect way to plug in app-specific behavior)
stoppable(server, wsconfig.stopTimeout);

// Load all RESTful endpoints
const routes = require('./routes/');
```

Comment: There are no `x` variables in your code. What is the actual error?

Comment: `Cannot access ‘server’ before initialization.` As mentioned in the question, it happens inside the `shutdown()` function on the line `server.on('close', function () { ` immediately upon startup.

Comment: Try moving `shutdown` so that it comes somewhere after `var server`.

Comment: @Ouroborus it is completely irrelevant, where `shutdown` and `var server = ...` are placed within the code, as long as it is assured, that `shutdown` isn't executed befor `server` is properly initialized ....

Comment: @derpirscher Sure. And if you make the change I suggested then apply the same tests, you get different results (as you detail in your answer) that might encourage one to think about why there might be a difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a runtime error, which happens only in a very specific situation. But actually this exact error shouldn't happen with `var server = ...` but only with `const server = ...` or `let server = ...`. With `var server = ...` the error message should say `"Cannot read properties of undefined"`

**What happens**

You have an error handler for `uncaughtException` which is calling `shutdown()` and in `shutdown()` you are referencing your `server`. But consider what happens if your code throws an exception *before*  you initialized your `server`. For instance if your cert or key cannot be read from the disk, cert or key are invalid ... So nothing will be assigned to `server`, and an exception will be raised.

Then the handler for your uncaught exception will fire and call the `shutdown()` function, which then tries to access the `server`, which of course hasn't been initialized yet.

**How to fix**

Check what the unhandled exception is, that is thrown before your server is initialized and fix it. In your production environment, there is probably no exception, because the configuration and environment is properly set up. But there is at least one issue in your develepment environment, which causes an exception.

**Difference between `var` and `const`**

And the difference between `var server = ...` and `const server = ...` is quite a subtle one. For both, the *declaration* of the variable is hoisted up to the top of their respective scope. In your case it's always global, also for `const`. But variables declared as `var` are assigned a value of `undefined` whereas variables declared as `let/const` are not initialized at all.

You can easily reproduce this error if you uncomment either `error1` or `error2` in the following code. But `error3` alone won't produce this `ReferenceError` because `bar` will already be initialized. You can also replace `const bar =`  with `var bar =`  and you will see, that you get a different error message.

```
process.on("uncaughtException", err => {
  console.log("uncaught exception");
  console.log(err);
  foo();
});


function foo() {
  console.log("foo");
  console.log(bar.name);
}

function init() {
  // throw new Error("error1");
  return { name: "foobar"}
}

// throw new Error("error2");
const bar = init();

//throw new Error("error3");
```

Comment: This is an incredible answer @derpirscher! Thank you! I set VSCode to trap uncaught exceptions and your hypothetical is exactly what was happening (an exception was thrown because the cert files weren't installed). Wow, I'll take the embarrassment because it feels so good not to feel crazy anymore! LOL

Comment: Before fixing the root cause I decided to try to fix the code inside `shutdown()` by adding `if(server){` but the same "Cannot access server" issue occurs. Why wouldn't the `if` avoid it?

Comment: because also `if (server)` tries to access an uninitialized variable and that is not allowed. It would probably work with `var server = ... ` (because then `server` would have been initialized with `undefined`) but not with `const/let server = ...` (which I'm pretty sure you had when this error occured for the first time)